# Google Cloud Dataflow Job failed: Found unexpected parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, data-processing

[FAILED NOTE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvEL5.png)
When I set up a Dataflow Pipeline and created a Job from template ('Text Files on Cloud Storage to BigQuery'), I meet this problem.

**Job creation failed: The workflow could not be created.  Causes: Found unexpected parameters: ['javascriptTextTransformReloadIntervalMinutes' (perhaps you meant 'javascriptTextTransformFunctionName')]**

I have checked my json and js file, there is no 'javascriptTextTransformReloadIntervalMinutes'.
I can't find this parameter.

I want solve this problem and create a Dataflow Job. And I have reported this problem to Google, they will reply me then I will write down the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Just let "Javascript UDF auto-reload Interval" blank when you submit the dataflow job, it seems that it doesn't allow default:0.